# PHP Session timeout too fast

Tags: php, session

Can you help me.

In my demo server when the user login, it's logout automatically for next 2 hours.
But when I place my web to production server, it' logout too fast (15minutes less, user will logout).

in production server, I use iis.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the PHP documentation on session configuration?

Comment: yes, i checked. there is no problem before i move my website to production server.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can helps you

```
ini_get(’session.gc_maxlifetime’)
ini_get(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’);
ini_get(‘session.gc_probability’);
ini_get(‘session.gc_divisor’);
```

When starting session try this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(8*60*60);
session_start();
```

Comment: is there any way for extending session timeout?